# Acknowledge a design company as source for my work

Tags: website-design

I started working on a website 3 years ago. For the first year, I worked with a design company that created the original look for the website.

Since then, I stopped working with them and I changed the technology used for this website. Because of this change, I had to re-design the website (adding animations, new features, new views, etc.).

In the end, my design is based on the work done by this company during the first year, and then, by the work I have done and the enhancement I have done to this design for 2 years.

I want to acknowledge the work they have done but without saying "Designed by xxx". Is there a "standard" formulation that states that the design is based on their work that I iterated upon ?

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this (and the question can seem weird but I couldn't find a way to search for this question on internet)
Thanks

Comment: Have you asked them what they'd like? Was there anything in your contract? Just being open and playing fair with the company may just be the easiest and best solution here.

Comment: "initial website design by X" would be okay I would think.

Comment: I think the standard would be to not credit them.

Comment: Hi Ebatsin, Welcome to Graphic Design StackExchange. We hope you enjoy sharing knowledge and experience here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question.
The order of the citations can make a difference however.

Put yourself first.

This site was produced and developed by "Ebatsin." Original site created by "The Design Company,"

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's some written agreement which contains a clause that they are *specifically* to receive design credit, you don't *have* to credit them at all.

Most designers are "unsung heroes" and never get direct credit for their work.

It's a nice thing to give them credit if you wish. How you do that is entirely up to you without a written agreement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a highly specific existing protocol for this: for myself I think the way I would handle this is to cite their contribution in my overall design citation - probably something like: "some initial design contributions by xx; all other site design & execution yy".

However, as stated in comments by Vincent, I would run that proposed citational solution by design company XX for their input - this will ease any potential later trouble for one, and is more ethically correct for another - both important if you hope to maintain a  positive working relationship with them.

Hope that helps.